# If a polynomial ring R[x] is PID then R[x] is ED.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If a polynomial ring R[x]  is PID then R[x] is ED.

I want to show this.

So i thought degree function.

And for any f(x) I put this

f(x)=a(x)q(x)+r(x)

f(x)=a(x)q'(x)+r'(x)

such that 
deg(r(x)) < deg(a(x)) and   deg(r'(x)) < deg(a(x))

And I want to show that such q(x) and r(x) is unique!

So for some n,  a^n(x)(f(x)-r(x))=f'(x)-r'(x)

Hmmmm....??? I can't do anymore...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $R$ is a ring, then $R[X]$ is a PID iff $R$ is a field.

Comment: Is not there direct proof?

Comment: If R is field then we can define degree function and so R(x) is ED.  Is this???

Comment: Isn't this a direct proof? $R[X]$ PID implies $R$ field implies $R[X]$ ED wrt to degree.